# i want to add Nuget Package Manager along with VS2017 installation. What will be the command?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, package, nuget

I tried running 
choco install visualstudio2017professional --params "--productKey ****-****-****-****" "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet" But NugetPackageManager is not installed. I dont have access to UI and need to do it via CLI
Expectation is that after installation is successful NuGet folder should be created at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Is it solved now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#command-line-parameters). You can try  command like:

```
vs_professional__xxx.xxx.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet --passive --wait
```

Here's the VS2017 professional [download link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=professional&rel=15&utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=link+cta&utm_content=download+commandline+parameters+vs2017).

I'm not sure if you need to specify the productKey, but when I test if the command worked just now, I didn't specify that. If the same command not work in your machine, you can try command like it:

```
vs_professional__xxx.xxx.exe --productKey xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet --passive --wait
```

And you don't have access to UI, you need to use `--quiet` or `--passive` switch:

--quite: Do not display any user interface while performing the installation.

--passive: Display the user interface, but do not request any interaction from the user. (Display a progress bar but not require any operaions of UI)

Note: It may need run the prompt(like cmd.exe) as admin.